# how to give restriction on same product adding to wish list in opencart?

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

when user add product in wish list but when user add same product in wish list. At that time i want to give alert message as product already added in wish list.

In which file will change the code.

Please help me.

Comment: At least mention what you tired?

Comment: @AbubakrDar I searched but i m not getting actual file. So please tell me the file path or file name.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if wishlist is available, then check if product_id is in wishlist array

```
if (isset($this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
 if (in_array($product_id, $this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Product is already in wishlist!");</script>';
 }
}
```

Comment: please tell me file name

Comment: @Dnyan should be the wishlist.php at controller/account

Comment: @llan Hasanov I have tried code like this but not working.                  if (isset($this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
   if (in_array($product_id, $this->session->data['wishlist'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Product is already in wishlist!");</script>';
   }
  }else{
  foreach ($this->session->data['wishlist'] as $key => $product_id) {
  } 
  }